# Regex String in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string

```
"Máy Tính Acer[Asprise 4741 | 058941144] - 302";
"Máy Tính Acer[Asprise 4741 | 058941145] - 302";
```

Now I want to use Regex to get 2 string result:

> 058941144
>
> 058941145

Comment: What is the pattern? What is the language you use?

Comment: Is it always "Máy Tính Acer[Asprise 4741 |  " and then "] - 302"?

Comment: Is allways that. and input have a multi that.

Comment: the input is :  "Name [Model|ID] - Room";

Comment: `\d{9}` if the number is always 9 digits and the only 9 digit number.

Comment: @user3453883 Didi you check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use look-ahead and look-behind assertions, you can use this regex to match between `|` and `]`:

```
(?<=\|\s)[0-9]+(?=])
```

In C#, you can use this code:

```
String input = "Máy Tính Acer[Asprise 4741 | 058941144] - 302";
String pattern = @"(?<=\|\s)[0-9]+(?=])";

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern).ToString();
```

If you want to match bases on the whole string you put in your question, you can use a longer regex that works in basically the same way as the one above:

```
String pattern = @"(?<=Máy Tính Acer\[Asprise\s4741\s\|\s)[0-9]+(?=]\s-\s302)";
```

For a more generic pattern that will match any charaters, use

```
String pattern = @"(?<=\|).+(?=])";
```

Comment: Did you use the code above? What is your input? Is it many lines?

Comment: the input that : "Name [Model|ID] - Room";

Comment: Well, that won't work as you specified digits in this position. See my update now.

Comment: @Szymon I had deleted my answer, and +1 for your working code